# Visual Studio Upgrade Issues

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I am working on a project that has mixed C# and C++ code. We just switched to VS 2015 and the code compiles just fine, runs, but then crashes at a certain point in the program (crashes with an access memory problem). Another thing to mention here is that some of the code I am using is unmanaged, so I can't step through the code to see where it breaks.

The code works just fine when all the C++ code is compiled with VS 2013 chosen as the platform toolset. Any ideas how you would go about debugging this or has anyone had a similar issue?

Comment: Everybody had this problem.  Get the original author of that C++ code involved, he'll know how to debug.  He had lots of practice.

Comment: Assuming that isn't possible, any good place to start?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are treating the C++ code as a black box and you say you don't have access to the developer, can you just keep using the VS2013 build for the C++?

When upgrading a project from VS 2013 to 2015, the main issues I've had are:

- The default VS 2015 install does not include C++, and even modifying
  your install and checking C++ does not install all of pieces like
  SDKs.
- Upgrading changed build flags.

If you have to guess at a fix without being able to debug the C++ yourself, you can start with this:

- Make sure you have C++ and the needed SDKs installed (if it builds **without errors or warnings** you've probably already accomplished this).
- Compare all C++ and Linker flags in VS2013 and VS2015.  Ideally the only difference would be the setting General > Platform Toolset changing to VS 2015 (v140)
- Update your post with any build warning and errors, after you look them up yourself and attempt to fix them

If that doesn't help, you could build a test harness to exercise the C++ and learn in a more controlled way what is crashing it.  But it would be much easier if you could involve a C++ developer.